# Python, Concurrency and asyncio: Problem adding a rotating proxy

Tags: python, concurrency, proxy, rotation, python-asyncio

I'm creating an optimized multi-threading app using asyncio and want to add a rotating proxy into the mix.

Starting with a sample taken from this outstanding article:

[Speed Up Your Python Program With Concurrency](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#asyncio-version)

I added a rotating proxy and it stopped working.  The code simply exits the function after touching the line for the proxy.

[image]

This little snippet of code works, but not when added to the main script as shown in the screenshot above.

```
import asyncio
import random as rnd
 
async def download_site():
    proxy_list = [
        ('38.39.205.220:80'),
        ('38.39.204.100:80'),
        ('38.39.204.101:80'),
        ('38.39.204.94:80')
        ]
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    proxy = rnd.choice(proxy_list)
    print(proxy)
 
asyncio.run(download_site())
```

And here's the full sample:

```
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp

# Sample code taken from here:
# https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#asyncio-version

# Info for adding headers for the proxy (Scroll toward the bottom)
# https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html

# Good read to possible improve performance on large lists of URLs
# https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webscraper.html


# RUN THIS METHOD TO SEE HOW IT WORKS.
# # Original Code (working...)  
# async def download_site(session, url):
#     async with session.get(url, proxy="http://proxy.com") as response:
#         print("Read {0} from {1}".format(response.content_length, url))

def get_proxy(self):
    proxy_list = [
    (754, '38.39.205.220:80'),
    (681, '38.39.204.100:80'),
    (682, '38.39.204.101:80'),
    (678, '38.39.204.94:80')
    ]
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    print(proxy[1])
    return proxy


async def download_site(session, url):
    proxy_list = [
        ('38.39.205.220:80'),
        ('38.39.204.100:80'),
        ('38.39.204.101:80'),
        ('38.39.204.94:80')
        ]
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    proxy = rnd.choice(proxy_list)
    print(proxy)
    async with session.get(url, proxy="http://" + proxy) as response:
        print("Read {0} from {1}".format(response.content_length, url))


async def download_all_sites(sites):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in sites:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(download_site(session, url))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


# Modified to loop thru only 1 URL to make debugging simple
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
        "https://www.jython.org",
       # "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] #* 80
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(download_all_sites(sites))
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Downloaded {len(sites)} sites in {duration} seconds")
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: How do you know that "execution hits this line"? Debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You use `return_exceptions=True` but you don't actually check the returned results for errors. You can use [asyncio.as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) to handle exceptions and get the earliest next result:

```
import asyncio
import random
import traceback

import aiohttp


URLS = ("https://stackoverflow.com",)
TIMEOUT = 5
PROXIES = (
    "http://38.39.205.220:80",
    "http://38.39.204.100:80",
    "http://38.39.204.101:80",
    "http://38.39.204.94:80",
)


def get_proxy():
    return random.choice(PROXIES)


async def download_site(session, url):
    proxy = get_proxy()

    print(f"Got proxy: {proxy}")

    async with session.get(url, proxy=f"{proxy}", timeout=TIMEOUT) as resp:
        print(f"{url}: {resp.status}")
        return await resp.text()


async def main():
    tasks = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in URLS:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(download_site(session, url)))

        for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            try:
                html = await coro
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
            else:
                print(len(html))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you HTF.  Does this work for you?  I get the error "Only http proxies are supported".  Those should have been http proxies and I even used my local home prox and a http url and still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, it does but I've tested only with my local proxy. This sounds like you didn't add `http://` prefix or perhaps you're using `socks` proxy?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding how to make this work.  I went back to the original post that does work and added  your modification. I removed the line "await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)" and added your code starting with "for coro" - and then html is "None" resulting in an exception.

Comment: The url I test with is "http".  this is where I added the proxy:
async with session.get(url, proxy="http://" + '38.39.205.220:80') as response:
I'm new to this.  how do I know if I'm using socks?

Comment: The example I provided should work with no problem. If you add `http://` prefix in the `get` method then your list of proxies shouldn't include it.

Comment: OK thank you for that clarification!  It works now!!
Now when I use a URL that successfully works when 'not' using asyncio - it fails.

The URL is https and I get a "400 Bad Request".
When I change it to http instead:
http//www.yellowpages.com/washington-dc/mip/bnsf-railway-496598824 

I get: resp.status = 404

which tells me yp does not accept http calls.  Is there a work around for this?  If not then I have to abandon asyncio

Comment: You need to make sure that you use a valid proxy. I don't think that all the IPs you provided are a valid proxy.